# Only one material applied to multiple objects

Tags: c++, opengl

**It turns out I was just being an idiot; this code works fine, it's just the data that was incorrect**

N.B. If any of @datenwolf's comments or answers don't make sense, it's because I've started this question again; it's difficult to phrase.

I'm writing an OpenGL Wavefont object loader. I can load and display the model, as well as do the same for materials. The problem I've run into now is that when I apply the *first* material from an array, that's the material used for all subsequent objects.

First off, I have my object drawing code. This loops through a vector of vectors (groups of faces to form material groups).

```
typedef struct
{
    GLfloat Ka[3];
    GLfloat Kd[3];
    GLfloat Ks[3];
    float Ns;               // Specular (coeff)
}
Material;

typedef struct
{
    int v1, v2, v3;
    int vn1, vn2, vn3;
    int vt1, vt2, vt3;
}
Face;

vector<Material> materials;
vector< vector<Face> > faces;

for(int g = 0; g < faces.size(); g++)
{
    // Apply material for this material group
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, materials[g].Ka);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, materials[g].Kd);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, materials[g].Ks);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, materials[g].Ns);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    // Loop through faces
    for(int f = 0; f < faces[g].size(); f++)
    {
        glNormal3f(normals[faces[g][f].vn1 - 1].x, normals[faces[g][f].vn1 - 1].y, normals[faces[g][f].vn1 - 1].z);
        glVertex3f(vertices[faces[g][f].v1 - 1].x, vertices[faces[g][f].v1 - 1].y, vertices[faces[g][f].v1 - 1].z);

        glNormal3f(normals[faces[g][f].vn2 - 1].x, normals[faces[g][f].vn2 - 1].y, normals[faces[g][f].vn2 - 1].z);
        glVertex3f(vertices[faces[g][f].v2 - 1].x, vertices[faces[g][f].v2 - 1].y, vertices[faces[g][f].v2 - 1].z);

        glNormal3f(normals[faces[g][f].vn3 - 1].x, normals[faces[g][f].vn3 - 1].y, normals[faces[g][f].vn3 - 1].z);
        glVertex3f(vertices[faces[g][f].v3 - 1].x, vertices[faces[g][f].v3 - 1].y, vertices[faces[g][f].v3 - 1].z);
    }

    glEnd();
}
```

As @datenwolf suggested, I tried all sorts of things with `GL_COLOR_MATERIAL` along with a load of other directives. I've taken some code I used in another project that works in terms of materials, so the only problem I can see now is the fact I'm using `vector<>` for the materials, although this shouldn't matter, should it?

To clarify, my question is this: how do I get OpenGL to apply multiple materials per frame? Should I try VBOs? I'll be moving to those eventually but right now all I want is a working implementation.

Comment: We need to see the context in which the render code is called. There's probably some state being left set, that clashes with your needs.

Comment: @datenwolf My question is now hideously long, but there's the code. If you need more/less, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the loop of the first snippet is within, or gets called by `model_draw`. But it would help if I knew the context of that render loop (the function in which the render loop is).

So there are two basic mistakes, not directly related to rendering a specific model, but about transformation setup.

You call `gluLookAt` at the beginning of `drawScene` but let it apply on whatever matrix is active. `gluLookAt` is ment to be used on the *modelview* matrix. The *projection* is something like the "lens"; manipulating the projection matrix is moving the lens around, leaving the film/sensor in place. Also you should set the projection in the `drawScene` function, too. Technically all the stuff you do in the "initialization" function, should in fact be done at the beginning of every rendering iteration; you will switch many of those states multiple times throughout rendering.

The usual order is

```
glClearColor
glClearDepth
glClear(...)

glViewport(...)

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluProjection OR glFrustum OR glOrtho OR custom_projection

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
gluLookAt OR custom_camera

render_scene()
```

Comment: Thanks datenwolf, however the code I have at the moment works while your correct code doesn't. Right now it's not a priority, but I'll definitely look into making my code correct. Thanks. Shame it doesn't solve my problem though.

Comment: @JamWaffles: The only thing I can think of is, that you somewhere mess up your OpenGL state. For example if you did a glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); each and every call of glColor will mess up your material settings.